# Why does requests_html return an empty list, although the selector or XPATH are correct?

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests, css-selectors, python-requests-html

I am trying to scrape data from AliExpress using requests_html and CSS selectors, but it always returns an empty list. Can you please help?

The code I used:

```
import time

from requests_html import HTMLSession


url = 'https://www.aliexpress.com/w/wholesale-test.html?catId=0&initiative_id=SB_20230516115154&SearchText=test&spm=a2g0o.home.1000002.0'


def create_session(url):
    session = HTMLSession()
    request = session.get(url)
    request.html.render(sleep = 25) #Because it is dynamic website, will wait until to load the page
    prod = request.html.find(
        '#root > div > div > div.right--container--1WU9aL4.right--hasPadding--52H__oG > div > div.content--container--2dDeH1y > div.list--gallery--34TropR')
    print(prod)

create_session(url)
```

The output:

```
[]
```

Please note that I tried to change the CSS selector as below,, and I always got an an empty list:

1: I tried: `prod = request.html.find('#root > div > div > div.right--container--1WU9aL4.right--hasPadding--52H__oG > div > div.content--container--2dDeH1y > div.list--gallery--34TropR')`

2- I tried: `prod = request.html.find('#root > div > div > div.right--container--1WU9aL4.right--hasPadding--52H__oG > div > div.content--container--2dDeH1y > div.list--gallery--34TropR > a:nth-child(1)')`

3- I tried: `prod = request.html.find('#root > div > div > div.right--container--1WU9aL4.right--hasPadding--52H__oG > div > div.content--container--2dDeH1y > div.list--gallery--34TropR > a:nth-child(n)')`

4: I tried: `prod = request.html.find('#root > div > div > div.right--container--1WU9aL4.right--hasPadding--52H__oG > div > div.content--container--2dDeH1y > div.list--gallery--34TropR > a')`

ried: `prod = request.html.find('#root > div > div > div.right--container--1WU9aL4.right--hasPadding--52H__oG > div > div.content--container--2dDeH1y')`

6: I tried: `prod = request.html.find('div.manhattan--container--1lP57Ag.cards--gallery--2o6yJVt')`

7: I tried: `prod = request.html.find('a.manhattan--container--1lP57Ag.cards--gallery--2o6yJVt')`

8- I tried: `prod = request.html.find('div.list--gallery--34TropR')`

and also got an an empty list. Can you help,, please?

**I note that sometimes it works and sometimes returns empty list**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved the issue by increasing the rendering time

Answer (score 1):

Use `div.list--gallery--34TropR > a` selector to find element list inside `div.list--gallery--34TropR`

You can also cross-verify whatever selector you try to use through Inspect Element in the browser devTools.

Comment: I also got empty list!

Comment: You can verify this selector's correctness through inspect element finds..it seems the error is somewhere else...can you try increasing delay, or checking if app has loaded completely.

Comment: I added delay, but sometime works and sometimes not

Comment: You have to make sure DOM is loaded then look for element

Comment: How can i do it? can you give me more details please?